# Kartoza/geoserver tomcat issue

Tags: tomcat, geoserver

I have a running geoserver connection using docker's kartoza geoserver & It's been running fine for past 5 months, but suddenly it throws error as follows,

```
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m 02-Nov-2021 06:44:12.664 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.open The specified user database [conf/tomcat-users.xml] could not be found
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m 02-Nov-2021 06:44:12.664 WARNING [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.backgroundProcess Failed to close [conf/tomcat-users.xml]
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m     java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml (No such file or directory)
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m             at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m             at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m             at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m             at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:112)
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m             at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:86)
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m             at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:184)
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m             at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.backgroundProcess(MemoryUserDatabase.java:685)
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m             at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.backgroundProcess(UserDatabaseRealm.java:141)
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m             at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.backgroundProcess(CombinedRealm.java:299)
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m             at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1130)
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m             at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1346)
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m             at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1328)
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m             at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m             at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m             at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m             at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m             at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m             at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m             at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[36mgeoserver_1  |[0m 02-Nov-2021 06:44:22.665 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.backgroundProcess Reloading memory user database [UserDatabase] from updated source [file:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml]
```

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  geoserver:
    restart: always
    image: kartoza/geoserver:2.18.0
    ports:
      - 8002:8080
    environment:
      - SAMPLE_DATA=false
      - STABLE_EXTENSIONS=vectortiles-plugin
    volumes:
      - geoserver_data:/opt/geoserver/data_dir
volumes:
  geoserver_data:
```

when I tried to restart the service & i got below error

```
geoserver_1  | 02-Nov-2021 07:47:43.930 INFO [Sync Timer Thread] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
geoserver_1  |  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
geoserver_1  |          at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1383)
geoserver_1  |          at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResources(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:983)
geoserver_1  |          at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResources(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1084)
geoserver_1  |          at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1195)
geoserver_1  |          at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1220)
geoserver_1  |          at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1264)
geoserver_1  |          at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1299)
geoserver_1  |          at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1384)
geoserver_1  |          at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder$1.run(FactoryFinder.java:287)
geoserver_1  |          at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
geoserver_1  |          at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:283)
geoserver_1  |          at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:261)
geoserver_1  |          at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:140)
geoserver_1  |          at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.XmlSupport.createPrefsDoc(XmlSupport.java:225)
geoserver_1  |          at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.XmlSupport.exportMap(XmlSupport.java:343)
geoserver_1  |          at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$7.run(FileSystemPreferences.java:641)
geoserver_1  |          at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$7.run(FileSystemPreferences.java:634)
geoserver_1  |          at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
geoserver_1  |          at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.writeBackCache(FileSystemPreferences.java:633)
geoserver_1  |          at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.syncSpiPrivileged(FileSystemPreferences.java:820)
geoserver_1  |          at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$12.run(FileSystemPreferences.java:790)
geoserver_1  |          at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$12.run(FileSystemPreferences.java:788)
geoserver_1  |          at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
geoserver_1  |          at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.syncSpi(FileSystemPreferences.java:787)
geoserver_1  |          at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences.sync2(AbstractPreferences.java:1381)
geoserver_1  |          at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences.sync2(AbstractPreferences.java:1386)
geoserver_1  |          at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.AbstractPreferences.sync(AbstractPreferences.java:1372)
geoserver_1  |          at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.sync(FileSystemPreferences.java:766)
geoserver_1  |          at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.flush(FileSystemPreferences.java:843)
geoserver_1  |          at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences.syncWorld(FileSystemPreferences.java:483)
geoserver_1  |          at java.prefs/java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$4$1.run(FileSystemPreferences.java:461)
geoserver_1  | 02-Nov-2021 07:47:43.938 INFO [Thread-10] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
geoserver_1  | 02-Nov-2021 07:47:43.962 INFO [Thread-10] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
geoserver_1  | 02-Nov-2021 07:47:43.976 INFO [Thread-10] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
geoserver_1  | 02-Nov-2021 07:47:43.999 INFO [Thread-10] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
geoserver_1  | 02-Nov-2021 07:47:44.025 INFO [Thread-10] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
geoserver_1  | 02-Nov-2021 07:47:44.062 INFO [Thread-10] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
geoserver_1  | 02-Nov-2021 07:47:44.074 INFO [Thread-10] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
geoserver_1  | Enabling vectortiles-plugin for GeoServer
geoserver_1  | Installing vectortiles-plugin plugin
geoserver_1  | unzip:  cannot find or open /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip, /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip.zip or /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip.ZIP.
geoserver_1  | mv: target '/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/' is not a directory
geoserver_1  | /scripts/entrypoint.sh: 33: exec: /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: not found
geoserver_1  | Enabling vectortiles-plugin for GeoServer
geoserver_1  | Installing vectortiles-plugin plugin
geoserver_1  | unzip:  cannot find or open /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip, /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip.zip or /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip.ZIP.
geoserver_1  | replace /tmp/tomcat/tomcat_apps/examples/WEB-INF/tags/panel.tag? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:  NULL
geoserver_1  | (EOF or read error, treating as "[N]one" ...)
geoserver_1  | /scripts/entrypoint.sh: 33: exec: /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: not found
geoserver_1  | Enabling vectortiles-plugin for GeoServer
geoserver_1  | Installing vectortiles-plugin plugin
geoserver_1  | unzip:  cannot find or open /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip, /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip.zip or /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip.ZIP.
geoserver_1  | replace /tmp/tomcat/tomcat_apps/examples/WEB-INF/tags/panel.tag? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:  NULL
geoserver_1  | (EOF or read error, treating as "[N]one" ...)
geoserver_1  | /scripts/entrypoint.sh: 33: exec: /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: not found
geoserver_1  | Enabling vectortiles-plugin for GeoServer
geoserver_1  | Installing vectortiles-plugin plugin
geoserver_1  | unzip:  cannot find or open /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip, /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip.zip or /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip.ZIP.
geoserver_1  | replace /tmp/tomcat/tomcat_apps/examples/WEB-INF/tags/panel.tag? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:  NULL
geoserver_1  | (EOF or read error, treating as "[N]one" ...)
geoserver_1  | /scripts/entrypoint.sh: 33: exec: /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: not found
geoserver_1  | Enabling vectortiles-plugin for GeoServer
geoserver_1  | Installing vectortiles-plugin plugin
geoserver_1  | unzip:  cannot find or open /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip, /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip.zip or /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip.ZIP.
geoserver_1  | replace /tmp/tomcat/tomcat_apps/examples/WEB-INF/tags/panel.tag? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:  NULL
geoserver_1  | (EOF or read error, treating as "[N]one" ...)
geoserver_1  | /scripts/entrypoint.sh: 33: exec: /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: not found
geoserver_1  | Enabling vectortiles-plugin for GeoServer
geoserver_1  | Installing vectortiles-plugin plugin
geoserver_1  | unzip:  cannot find or open /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip, /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip.zip or /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip.ZIP.
geoserver_1  | replace /tmp/tomcat/tomcat_apps/examples/WEB-INF/tags/panel.tag? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:  NULL
geoserver_1  | (EOF or read error, treating as "[N]one" ...)
geoserver_1  | /scripts/entrypoint.sh: 33: exec: /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: not found
geoserver_1  | Enabling vectortiles-plugin for GeoServer
geoserver_1  | Installing vectortiles-plugin plugin
geoserver_1  | unzip:  cannot find or open /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip, /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip.zip or /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip.ZIP.
geoserver_1  | replace /tmp/tomcat/tomcat_apps/examples/WEB-INF/tags/panel.tag? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:  NULL
geoserver_1  | (EOF or read error, treating as "[N]one" ...)
geoserver_1  | /scripts/entrypoint.sh: 33: exec: /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: not found
geoserver_1  | Enabling vectortiles-plugin for GeoServer
geoserver_1  | Installing vectortiles-plugin plugin
geoserver_1  | unzip:  cannot find or open /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip, /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip.zip or /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip.ZIP.
geoserver_1  | replace /tmp/tomcat/tomcat_apps/examples/WEB-INF/tags/panel.tag? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:  NULL
geoserver_1  | (EOF or read error, treating as "[N]one" ...)
geoserver_1  | /scripts/entrypoint.sh: 33: exec: /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: not found
geoserver_1  | Enabling vectortiles-plugin for GeoServer
geoserver_1  | Installing vectortiles-plugin plugin
geoserver_1  | unzip:  cannot find or open /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip, /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip.zip or /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip.ZIP.
geoserver_1  | replace /tmp/tomcat/tomcat_apps/examples/WEB-INF/tags/panel.tag? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:  NULL
geoserver_1  | (EOF or read error, treating as "[N]one" ...)
geoserver_1  | /scripts/entrypoint.sh: 33: exec: /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: not found
geoserver_1  | Enabling vectortiles-plugin for GeoServer
geoserver_1  | Installing vectortiles-plugin plugin
geoserver_1  | unzip:  cannot find or open /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip, /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip.zip or /plugins/vectortiles-plugin.zip.ZIP.
geoserver_1  | replace /tmp/tomcat/tomcat_apps/examples/WEB-INF/tags/panel.tag? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:  NULL
geoserver_1  | (EOF or read error, treating as "[N]one" ...)
geoserver_1  | /scripts/entrypoint.sh: 33: exec: /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: not found
```

1. tomcat version 9.0.20
2. goeserver version 2.18
3. Min/max memory 2G/4G

I found the temporary solution by changing the volume name. its works fine for one day & issue starts again
How to rectify this issue?

Comment: You need to look at the log above the part you are showing - did the disk fill?

Comment: For the first time log file size was very high 18MB( i think), On the second time, log file was less than 2MB. Now, I have updated the logging drive configuration.

Comment: Looks like your install of tomcat is broken `/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: not found` or you have set `CATALINIA_HOME` to point to the wrong place